# grabbing the data from a field as it is typed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am wondering what I would use to grab data from a form as it is typed. What I have is some form Input fields and they are going to be filled with numbers. I want to take the input from them on the fly add them together and put them inside another div on the fly. The idea is the user is entering different amounts and sizes of bottles into a form and I want to show them what their total is in bottles as they type it. Would I be doing this in ajax? what would help me get the data as they type it and place it back on the page at the same time.

Comment: No ajax needed. You can do it `onkeyup` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var output_element = $('#output_ele');

    $('#the_input_id').keyup(function() {  
        var their_input = $(this).val();
        output_element.text(their_input);

        // Now go off and do whatever you wanted with AJAX and their_value
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the jQuery library at http://www.jquery.com to start with. That wraps up a whole bunch of browser inconsistencies into a manageable solid set of tools.

Specifically, have a look at the keyboard events, and the functions for manipulating dom elements. You'll see that you can write a key event handler for your fields which would perform your calculation and write the results into any other element you like.